# Page Object model in Selenium 2 with C#. Cannot convert a base class object into a subclass.

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create tests with selenium2, using Page Object pattern. So, I have several classes:

```
public class WebPage
{
protected IWebDriver webDriver;

public DataPage( IWebDriver d)  
{
this.webDriver = d; 
PageFactory.InitElements(webDriver, this);
}
}


public class WebForm : WebPage
{
public WebForm(IWebDriver d) : base(d) { }
public DataPage SubmitForm()
{
//Some code here
return new DataPage(webDriver);
}
}

public class ResultPage : WebPage
{
public ResultForm(IWebDriver d) : base(d) { }
}
```

WebPage class is common class for any web pages.
So, my problem, that I may get object of any class as result of the SubmitForm() method. It depends of test. If I want to test unsuccessful submission, I'll stay on the same form and I want to have WebForm object as result of SubmitForm() method. If submission is successful, so I may be redirected to result page, so I need ResultPage object to be returned. But when I use:

```
WebForm DP = NewForm.SubmitForm() as WebForm;
```

I get error: 
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am not familiar with C# and Object oriented programming, and with Selenium. So, maybe all my structure is wrong.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A `DataPage` isn't a `WebForm`, so the `as` operator will return null. It's generally a better idea to use casting than `as`, unless it's valid (not a bug) for the value to genuinely not be appropriate for the cast.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, to be honest - but it does sound like your structure is off. If you're unfamiliar with C# and OOP in general, I would *strongly* advise you to put Selenium down for the moment, and concentrate on learning the basics of C# first. Come back to Selenium when the only "new" and challenging thing will be Selenium itself. Otherwise it's like deciding to perform Hamlet in Japanese on a unicycle, without being familiar with Shakespeare, Japanese or unicycles...

Comment: Hi Jon. Thank you for replay. Actually I have some basic knowledge about object oriented programming, I studied it in University and write simple projects long time ago. Now, I am trying to study C# and OOP and at the same time create some structure for my tests.

Comment: @yana_cas: But I'd suggest writing small console apps (and yes, unit tests for them) instead of going straight into web development, which has its own extra set of challenges. You're likely to be much more successful if you try to take one step at a time.

Comment: I already tried to write small applications and tests for them. And I understand how it works, but I have a task to test some web pages (that are created with help of special program) and I stack on classes’ structure. So my testing is testing of some WebPages. There are several types of webpages: WebForm, ResultPage, CalendarPage etc. My idea is to have a class for each of them, because they have common structure, like each result page has a table with some data, and some buttons. WebForm is a form with some fields and submit button, after this form submission I may be redirected to any page.

Comment: When I write tests I will know which page it will be. When I test negative case: some fields are filled with incorrect value or required fields are empty, after form submission I will stay on the same page and see errors. So, in this case SubmitForm method has to return the same WebForm.  And my idea was to create parent class WebPage, that have common methods (like Open, VerifyErrors, etc) and members (errormessage element, etc), and make SubmitForm method to return an instance of this class. But now I cannot convert instance of parent class to a child class.

Comment: @yana_cas: If you understand how it works, why are you trying to convert a `DataPage` to a `WebForm`? (In fact your sample code is unclear as your `DataPage` constructor is within a `WebPage` class declaration, but...) Basically, I don't think your `SubmitForm` method does what you want it to - but I don't really follow what you're trying to get it to do. Does the Selenium documentation not give examples of this sort of thing?

Comment: "So, in this case SubmitForm method has to return the same WebForm." But it doesn't. It returns a `DataPage`, like this: `return new DataPage(webDriver);` Why are you returning `DataPage`?

Comment: Because in case of incorrect submission, I need to return WebForm, but in case of successful submission, I may have ResultPage or WebForm, or CalendarPage. Because any of these pages may be used as redirection after form submission. Actually and WebPage may be used as redirection after form submission.

Comment: @yana_cas: But if you want to return a `WebForm` then you *can't* declare that the method returns `DataPage` - because a `WebForm` simply *isn't* a `DataPage`. You need to think about what return type you really need from `SubmitForm`, and what sort of type hierarchy would be appropriate.